# Proof that circuit upper bounds for $E$ imply $P \neq NP$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity

In the official Clay problem description for P versus NP it's stated that $P \neq NP$ would follow from showing that "every language in $E$ [the class of languages recognizable in exponential time with a deterministic Turing machine] can be computed by a Boolean circuit family $<B_n>$ such that for at least one $n$, $B_n$ has fewer gates than the maximum needed to
compute any Boolean function $f: \{0,1\}^n \longrightarrow \{0,1\}$." However, the only reference is that this "is an intriguing observation by V. Kabanets." Could someone please point me to a published version of this implication with the proof?

Answer (score 25):

I don't think the paper in the other answer contains an answer to your question. Indeed I am not really sure a proof has been published, because the result follows from other well known results.

The proof of the statement you want is as follows:

1. $\Sigma_3 E$ contains a function of maximum possible circuit complexity on every input length, by simply defining a function which proves itself (using alternation) to be different from all functions with non-maximum circuit complexity. This is standard and the proof idea can be found in sources such as Arora and Barak's textbook.
2. If $P = NP$ then $\Sigma_3 E = E$, by padding and the collapse of the polynomial time hierarchy to $P $.
3. Therefore if $P = NP$ then there is a language in $E$ with maximum circuit complexity. This is the contrapositive of what you want to prove.

Comment: Nice, I guessed that you would be the first one to answer it.

Comment: There is also an answer in the  paper of Kabanets and Cai. In Theorem 10 they prove that if $MCSP$ is in $P$, then $E^{NP}$ contains a family of Boolean functions of maximum circuit complexity. If $P=NP$, then $MCSP\in P$ and $E^{NP}=E$, so then, by the Theorem, $E$ indeed contains a language with maximum complexity.

Comment: good point, Andras! One of the quantifiers in the  $\Sigma_3 E $ part can be seen as solving  MCSP.

Answer (score 6):

googling around found me this paper which was published with the refrence below.

> Circuit minimization problem
>
> **Valentine Kabanets and Jin-Yi Cai**
>
> *We study the complexity of the circuit minimization problem: given the truth table of a Boolean function f and a parameter s, decide whether f can be realized by a Boolean circuit of size at most s. We argue why this problem is unlikely to be in P (or even in P/poly) by giving a number of surprising consequences of such an assumption. We also argue that proving this problem to be NP-complete (if it is indeed true) would imply proving strong circuit lower bounds for the class E, which appears beyond the currently known techniques.*

This appeared to be published below.

1. extended abstract in Proceedings of the Thirty-Second Annual ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing (STOC'00), pages 73-79, 2000.
   technical report, in Electronic Colloquium on Computational Complexity TR99-045, 1999.
   [http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/Research/circuit.html](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Ekabanets/Research/circuit.html)
2. extended abstract in Proceedings of the Thirty-Second Annual ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing (STOC'00), pages 73-79, 2000.
   http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/1999/045/

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't answer the above question but it does provide the reference which this question originated in.